# Computer beeping on startup after unsuccessfully RAM upgrade

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I tried to upgrade my RAM, but when I opened the computer and tried to put them in, I realized that I have DDR2, and I had bought DDR3. Well, nevermind, I will exchange them, but here is the problem: When I put my old memory back into my computer and tied to turn it on, I just hear strange beeps and nothing is happening on the screen.

What I tried so far:

- changed my 2 old RAM sticks over every slot;
- unplugged all power and wires and tried again;
- unplugged all power and wires and removed RAM and removed battery from motherboard for a few minutes and pressed power button few times and then put back battery and tried again;
- blew the dust from RAM sticks and from motherboard;
- checked if the motherboard is burned.
- tried to put sticks inside by pressing left side first and then right one; also did the opposite; tried pressing both sides in at same the time as well.

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Did you handle the memory the proper way?

Comment: As a side note -- before you exchange the RAM use a [tool such as this system scanner](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/) to find out exactly what type of RAM your system will take.  You also don't want to buy the wrong speed, etc.

Comment: Do the RAM stick _smell_ burned? Are you sure you are inserting them all the way in? Do they _click_ into place?

Comment: i did handle it in the proper way. i didnt use system scaner, but i guess its too late now. 
smell burned

Comment: they dont smell burned. and they clicked into place.

Comment: @user2834926 right but since you need to exchange the ddr3 for ddr2 anyway, I'd... er, nevermind you can't now, can you? :-/  What is the system make & model? (or for the motherboard if it's some custom-built thing)

Comment: what type of motherboard & what set of beeps?  Each type of beep set means something different.  My bet is just that you didn't fully seat the memory, but knowing the code it's beeping would help. Like this: http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Comment: What are your beeps? See http://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the RAM is not correctly in the slots or the RAM has been damaged when you have moved or taken them out. Try with just 1 stick at a time (If you have more than one)

If not all the sticks may be broken in which case you will have to buy more.

Comment: i tried,still nothing :( i will buy new ones tomorrow. ty

Comment: Cool. That should fix the problem you are having :).

Comment: Or maybe the motherboard?  That seems like it would almost be more likely than *both* ram sticks going bad. @user2834926